# Convert 8 Digit Number into Date in SQL

Tags: sql, date, format

I have a date field that is pulling from a server as just an 8 digit number, and I would like to convert it to a standard date format.

For example, "`20140501`" would be converted to `05-01-2014`

I tried using the `DateTime` code, but that didn't work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: please post the database engine and version that you are using

Comment: To troubleshoot, please show what you tried and let us know what specifically went wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Many databases might recognize the string '20140501' as a date, because this is an ISO standard format.  Hence, you might try this:

```
select cast(cast(datecol as varchar(255)) as date)
```

Whether or not this works depends on your database.